# I am upgrading from 11.1.0.7.0 to 11.2.0.3 with R12.1.3 while pre upgrade/catupgrd.sql erroring out ORA-00600

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, upgrade

While upgrading from 11.1.0.7.0 to 11.2.0.3 with R12.1.3, during running the pre upgrade script catupgrd.sql, it is erroring out

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qcisSetPlsqlCtx:tzi
 init], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

I applied patch `10272702`, the patch got applied successfully but still the persist.

Comment: googling suggests 2 things. "Increase parameters to at least 3G SGA, 1G PGA, 250 session cashed cursors.". Or that the time zone data in the database needs updating. In the first instance, use the ORA-600 lookup tool on the Oracle support site.

Comment: It suggested the Patch and I applied.

Comment: Gave all the specified parameters like SGA,PGA,SCC greater than specified values still same error.

Comment: Open an SR with Oracle...

Comment: Thank you Phil, but I'm doing this on my personal server can I raise an SR ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to timezone stuff. Did you execute the pre-upgrade (utlu112i.sql) scripts? And did you follow the instructions?

Comment: Yeah I followed all instructions 1058763.1 according to this Doc. But in this doc they haven't asked to run this script. Where shall I run this script? 11.2.0.3 or 11.0.7 ?

Comment: The script comes with the new Oracle installation. But you have to run it before the upgrade from the 11.0.7 home.